# Magento 2: Using dockerize-magento2 create enviroment to install magento 2

Tags: magento2, docker

I am a beginner using docker to create web environment. I want to install magento 2.
I use https://github.com/arvatoSCM/dockerize-magento2/ to create images, container and install magento 2.
But when I'm installing, it has a error: `bin/magento permission denied`.
I change command line at file `bin/console` in `executeInDocker` function:

> line 137 - docker exec -it -u www-data $phpContainerName bash -c
>   "bin/magento $*"

to:

> line 137 - docker exec -it -u root $phpContainerName bash -c
>   "bin/magento $*"

It works. But when install completed. I cannot go to frontend or backend.

> Error 404 nginx

Now, I'm just wanted to create environment with: `nginx, php, mysql, alpine, redis`, `phpmyadmin` with `docker`, and `config nginx config`, `php extensions` to install magento 2?